Linear substitution in a double integral
Evaluate the following integral, using appropriate linear substitutions: $$V=\int \int_R 2x^2+4xy+3y^2$$ where $R$ is the region enclosed by $y=-\dfrac{3}{2}x+2, y=-\dfrac{3}{2}x+4, y=-\dfrac{1}{4}x,y=-\dfrac{1}{4}x+3$.
My attempt:
I know how to evaluate this by dividing into 3 regions, and summing the integral over them as follows;
$$\int_{2.8}^{3.2} \int_{\frac{2}{3}(2-y)}^{4(3-y)} 2x^2+4xy+3y^2 \, dx \, dy+\int_{-0.4}^{2.8} \int_{\frac{2}{3}(2-y)}^{\frac{2}{3}(4-y)} 2x^2+4xy+3y^2 \, dx \, dy+\int_{-0.8}^{-0.4} \int_{-4y}^{\frac{2}{3}(4-y)} 2x^2+4xy+3y^2 \, dx \, dy$$

However, I do not understand what substitution should I make here to simplify the boundaries of the region. In the solution, they have made the substitution $u=3x+4y,v=x+4y$ which forms a simple rectangular region in the $u-v$ graph.
I thought of $x=a_1u+b_1v,y=a_2u+b_2v$ and then substituting this into the given equations of the lines, and then using the condition for perpendicular lines $m_1m_2=-1$, but that only gives me one equation in $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2$ i.e. 4 variables. So, I'm unable to determine the coefficients. How can I come up with such a linear substitution that transforms a parallelogram region into a rectangular one? Is there a way I can simplify trapezoidal region boundaries as well?

For the parallelogram, try affine linear equations $u=ax+by+c$, $v=dx+ey+f$, and choose the constants so that the four vertices of the parallelogram go to the four vertices of the unit square. That will give you eight linear equations (two of them redundant) in six unknowns, and leave you with a very nice region of integration.
For trapezoids, I would try to aim for a similarly nice region—say two sides of the trapezoid are vertical and the left side is on the $y$-axis centered at the origin. That's easy to integrate over as well.

In the first line, what is $x_b$? Maybe you meant $ax+by+c$ ?

No need to solve any linear equations if you write the change of variables in the other direction! Just take $(x,y) = P + u \mathbf{f}_1 + v \mathbf{f}_2$, where $P$ is one of the vertices of the parallelogram, and $\mathbf{f}_1$ and  $\mathbf{f}_2$ are the vectors from $P$ to the two adjacent vertices. Then you automatically get the unit square in the $(u,v)$-plane. And you also directly get the expressions for $x$ and $y$ to substitute in the integrand.

You can transform a parallelogram in the $x$-$y$ plane into a rectangle in the $u$-$v$ plane by writing the equations for the slanted lines in the form $f(x,y)=c$ and $g(x,y)=d$ for some constants $c$ and $d$. Then you set $u=f(x,y)$ and $v=g(x,y)$, since setting $u$ and $v$ equal to constants defines a rectangle.
In this case, the parallel lines $y=-\frac{3}{2}x+2$ and $y=-\frac{3}{2}x+4$ can equivalently be written as $3x+2y=4$ and $3x+2y=8$, so set $u=3x+2y\in[4,8]$. Similarly you find $v=x+4y\in[0,12]$.
You can then manipulate the two expressions to find $x$ and $y$ in terms of $u$ and $v$: $x=\frac{2u-v}{5}$ and $y=\frac{3v-u}{10}$.
The final step is to write the area element $dxdy$ in terms of $du$ and $dv$, for which we need the Jacobian $$\begin{vmatrix}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\\\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}\frac{2}{5}&-\frac{1}{5}\\-\frac{1}{10}&\frac{3}{10}\end{vmatrix}=\frac{1}{10}$$ so $dxdy=\frac{1}{10}dudv$.
So now you can write your integral entirely in terms of $u$ and $v$ and solve the integral on a rectangular boundary: $$\frac{1}{10}\int_0^{12}\int_4^82\frac{(2u-v)^2}{5^2}+4\frac{(2u-v)(3v-u)}{5\cdot10}+3\frac{(3v-u)^2}{10^2}\,{\rm d}u\,{\rm d}v$$$$=\frac{1}{1000}\int_0^{12}\int_4^819u^2+6uv+11v^2\,{\rm d}u\,{\rm d}v$$$$=\frac{1}{1000}\int_0^{12}\frac{8512}{3}+144v+44v^2\,{\rm d}v$$$$=69.76$$
As an additional note, for a trapezoidal region, since there is only one pair of parallel lines, I don't think you could use this method to transform the region into a rectangle (though I'm sure there will be a different method to do this). However you could follow this procedure for the single pair of parallel lines, replacing one of $x$ or $y$ with $u$ - let's say $x$ WLOG - giving a region bounded between two lines of constant $u$ and between two polynomials $y=f(u)$ and $y=g(u)$, for which an integral should be a little easier to compute. You could even add a further transformation to turn the bottom $y$ boundary into $v=0$.
